# TypeScript: Accessing a generic object to generate typed functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface that provides a `decode` function

```
interface Converter<T> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: T) => Buffer;
  encode?: (value: Buffer) => T;
}
```

No I have a class called `Service` that provides an object that contains any number of these Converters:

```
type Converters = { name: Converter<any> };

class Service<C extends Converters> {

}
```

So that I can pass these kind of objects to the `Service`:

```
interface MyConverters extends Converters {
  state: Converter<string>;
  water: Converter<number>;
}

const service = new Service<MyConverters>();
```

The `Service` class has a couple of functions that *should* work on the `Converters` and on the Generic `T` (`Converter<T>`) that is passed to the converter. So instead of doing this:

```
class Service<C extends Converters> {

  public write(name: string, value: any): void {

  }

}
```

I want the `name` to be any key in `Converters` and `value` to be the `ReturnType` of the `decode` function of the corresponding `Converter` that is `Converters[name]` (so basically the `<T>` of `Converter<T>`).

This is what I have finally come up with:

```
interface Converter<T> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: T) => Buffer;
  encode?: (value: Buffer) => T;
}

type Converters = { name: Converter<any> };

type ConverterNames<C extends Converters> = keyof C;

type ConverterValue<C extends Converters, N extends Keys<C>> = ReturnType<C[N]["decode"]>;

class Service<C extends Converters> {

  public write<N extends ConverterNames<C>>(
    name: N,
    value: ConverterValue<C, N>
  ): void {}

}
```

…BUT it does not work at

```
type ConverterValue<C extends Converters, N extends ConverterNames<C>> = ReturnType<C[N]["decode"]>;
                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am getting the error

> ```
> Type 'C[N]["decode"]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
>   Type 'C[keyof C]["decode"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
>     Type 'C[string]["decode"] | C[number]["decode"] | C[symbol]["decode"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
>       Type 'C[string]["decode"]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.ts(2344)
> Type '"decode"' cannot be used to index type 'C[N]'.ts(2536)
> ```

And I am not sure what's happening.

Ultimately I want to make this possible:

```
interface MyConverters extends Converters {
  state: Converter<string>;
  water: Converter<number>;
}

const service = new Service<MyConverters>();

service.write("water", 12);
                 ^      ^
                          checks if these 2 types match MyConverters
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `ReturnType<C[N]["decode"]>` as that will always be buffer. Maybe you meant `encode` ?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a copy paste error, actually the params and return types are vice-versa. If you change your answer I can change my question to get this thread clean

Comment: I don't think it matters much for the bulk of the answer. The edit I made makes the extraction of the argument work either way.

Comment: that's cool! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a couple of things before we start:

- `type Converters = { name: Converter<any> };` is not an object with an key mapped to a `Converter<any>`, it's an object with one key, `name`, that's mapped to a `Converter<any>`, I suspect you want something like `type Converters = { [name: string]: Converter<any>; }`, but that will not work either. See below.
- I don't think it's possible to constrain the generic to `{ [name: string]: Converter<any>; }` because any extending type will need to provide the index signature (i.e. allow for any string to be accessed, and that's *not* what you want.

The best I've came to was

```
interface Converter<T> {
    uuid: CUUID;
    decode: (value: T) => Buffer;
    encode?: (value: Buffer) => T;
}


class Service<C> {
    public write<K extends keyof C>(
        name: K,
        value: C[K] extends Converter<infer R> ? R : never
    ): void { }
}

interface MyConverters {
    state: Converter<string>;
    water: Converter<number>;
}

const service = new Service<MyConverters>();

service.write('water', 'foo'); // Error, expected number.
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgqnAkgESgXigbwL4G4BQokUAQgK4BmFEATulnvvgJYB2wtFAhgMbQwB7VgDdaHGgB4AKgD4s+KIqhkyzACYAuWAhQElUNRB4DDWgBTCuAGzIQtUgJTo55KrT1KIrY4YD85yxs7UkpqGic0OSkCbCZ8HisuAGckqABlWmFmPgkYOUwFJTAyACMrbKgAdxpmDgkAaSgIAA8OVjVUgGsIEAEKWBkzQv1FVi4AW2D6gBphkcDbLRgAbXqAXSbWrw7YIVEacQk2MKgAJTlfM6gtVgh9uYctYQF1LChY2JZ2Tl5oAFkQIIRGJaKkCvoksAuBwlnsQZJITVWABzGQeRSVaG0WHAg60CSsMjjEq0NH4T7GViQqBJTLZaAYW6VdJ0nIAoH7cRJQYOAj4Wk0LJ8AB01VqEDMAHJMeJJdMoJKKAIBJLeUA)

---

In short, I'm giving up the `extends Converters` in favor of conditional inference. Also, I'm inferring the `T` from `Converter<T>` as opposed to `ReturnType<Converter<T>['decoder']>`, seeing how `ReturnType` uses conditional inference behind the scenes anyway, it seemed simpler this way.

If you try to pass a key that's not a Converter, your `write` call will not compile, no matter what value you provide.

Comment: `C[K] extends Converter<infer R> ? R : never` is definitely nicer, ashamed I didn't think about it 

Comment: Ok I am in awe, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you have is the way `Converters` looks. That is just a type with a `name` key of type `Converter<any>`. You probably wanted to write `type Converters = { [name: string]: Converter<any> };` meaning a type with an index signature, which would be closer but would not work as expected on the  `write` call as `keyof C` would actually end up being `string | number` since the interface can have any keys.

The solution is to use `Record<K, Converter<any>` as the constraint, where `K` will be the keys of whatever type we are passing in:

```
interface Converter<T> {
  uuid: CUUID;
  decode: (value: T) => Buffer;
  encode?: (value: Buffer) => T;
}


type Converters<K extends PropertyKey> = Record<K, Converter<any>>


type ConverterValue<C extends Converters<keyof C>, N extends keyof C> = Parameters<C[N]["decode"]>[0];

class Service<C extends Converters<keyof C>> {

  public write<N extends keyof C>(
    name: N,
    value: ConverterValue<C, N>
  ): void {}

}

interface MyConverters extends Converters<keyof MyConverters> {
  state: Converter<string>;
  water: Converter<number>;
}

const service = new Service<MyConverters>();

service.write("water", 12);
service.write("water", "12"); // err
service.write("state", "");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

**Edit**
@Madara Uchiha♦ version of ConverterValue is nicer than mine, I would use that.

```
type ConverterValue<C extends Converters<keyof C>, N extends keyof C> = C[N] extends Converter<infer R> ? R : never;
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it's not really recursive, think of `keyof T` as a completely separate type, just happens to be the keys of `T` 

Comment: omg, you are a god, this works. I have been struggling with this for so long and the solution is so on point. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok Imma accept @MadaraUchiha 's answer as it is a little cleaner. Still, thank you!

Comment: @Lukas Your call, his answer does not  constrain `C` to be anything, that can be both a good thing and a bad thing